# Cannot read property 'style' of null - in Chrome's Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, null

I was checking the JS console out and it helped me fix a few minor issues, but I would like to know if this warning is anything to seriously worry about?

This is the code which gives the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.safaviehhome.com/product_images/locations/js/jqgalscroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.safaviehhome.com/product_images/mainnav/stuHover.js"             type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function layerSetup(id,visibility){
if(document.getElementById){
this.obj = document.getElementById(id).style;
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
<!--Includes many more of the same "Cannot read property 'style' of null messages -->

this.obj.visibility = visibility;
return this.obj;}
else if(document.all){
this.obj = document.all[id].style;
this.obj.visibility = visibility;
return this.obj;}
else if(document.layers){
this.obj = document.layers[id];
this.obj.visibility = visibility;
return this.obj;}
}
function visVisible(param){
new layerSetup(param,'visible');
}

function visHidden(param){
new layerSetup(param,'hidden');
}</script>
```

I cannot really figure out why this is happening and whether it's something I should worry about since our Rug categories function fine. Can anybody offer any insight? I apologize for not offering any of my own explanations but I didn't write this JS a former co-worked did and it's now up to me to debug every mistake he made. It's a learning process but I'm still somewhat new to this ..

Comment: Without seeing your markup or how `layerSetup` is being called, I'd guess that you are trying to get an element by ID that does not exist in your document.

Answer (score 2):

This could be happening for two reasons.

1. Somewhere on the page the `layerSetup` function is being called with `null` as one of the parameters.
2. An element with the id being passed the the `layerSetup` function does not exist on the page.

In the Chrome dev console you can click `Pause on All Exceptions`, a button in the bottom left bar with a *pause* symbol. This will help you to determine what the parameters are that are being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid document.all

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/

http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/

Comment: But that's not where the error is being thrown, though I'm sure it wont help matters.